# R: How to keep vectors with a specific number of elements in a list?

Tags: r, list, vector

Is there any way or function to keep only vectors contain two elements from a list of vectors.

```
l<- list( c(24,56) , c(23,5,16), c(2,5),c(10,14,13,25), 
             c(12,33) ,c(1,2),c(3,5,6),c(10,14))
```

The result will be :

```
   > l
   [[1]]
   [1] 24 56

   [[2]]
   [1] 2 5

   [[3]]
   [1] 12 33

   [[4]]
   [1] 1 2
```

Comment: `l <- l[lengths(l) == 2]`?

Comment: Or `Filter`. `Filter(function(x) length(x)==2, l)`

Answer (score 1):

For future readers and to consider this question "answered", two solutions to this are:

1. `Filter(function(x) length(x)==2, l)`
2. `l <- l[lengths(l) == 2]`

Both of which return:

```
#[[1]]
#[1] 24 56
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 2 5
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 12 33
#
#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2
#
#[[5]]
#[1] 10 14
```

Credit to @docendodiscimus for the second solution.